# How to make REST requests more user friendly like RPC?

Tags: php, api, rest, rpc

I've been highly considering creating a REST service rather than RPC but it seems to me that a client/user will have to write a significant amount of code to achieve the same thing compared with an RPC service. Moreover, implementing a REST service would require a user some basic knowledge about REST. To illustrate in PHP:

**REST**

- To send GET, POST, PUT, DELETE request the user must send his request using CURL
- Of course this requires his server to have CURL enabled, not good for some shared host
- Aside from the data parameters the users needs to send, CURL requires additional lines of code to send the request.

**RPC**

- To send a similar request with an RPC service, the user simply calls a URL together with data parameters. ie: example.com?foo=bar&baz=quz

Is there a way to make REST as "easy" as RPC. I'm thinking of encapsulating REST request with RPC methods but that breaks the whole idea isn't it?

Comment: What makes you think a rest service cannot be called via a URL ?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder how do you send a PUT POST DELETE request via URL?

Comment: IMB, fair enough, you wouldn't be able to do those.

Answer (score 1):

REST does not force you to use GET, POST, PUT and DELETE. it just means that a single URL represents a single content. you can also implement a RESTful behaviour like this:

```
GET /index.php
GET /item.php?id=x
POST /create.php
POST /update.php
POST /delete.php
```

even create, update and delete could be done with get requests...

Comment: Would that look like an RPC service now since you'll be basically using GET only? And, there is no more uniform "resource". In a RESTful point of view `index`, `item`, `create`, `update`, `delete`, are a bunch of different resources. In RPC they can mean the same resource. Well I guess I can implement that however it is no longer RESTful, just REST'sh :-)

Comment: RPC usually has a single access point which you pass the method to be called and the params to pass to the method, ie. in XML, JOSN, YAML etc. in a single POST variable.

Comment: That is true, however POST is not always required nor is enforced as a standard. Back to your original suggestion for the purist, using create, update and delete actions for GET requests breaks the RESTful standard principles. Well I guess my whole intention was to indeed break it so it can be easier for users so they don't have to explicitly use CURL just to send PUT POST DELETE. Having said that, I guess your suggestion will do.